# Node.js / Intellij: http post request returns code 404

Tags: node.js, http, endpoint

I get this response when testing the http method:

```
http://localhost:3000/rooms
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

This is the code for my routing / endpoint

```
router.post('/rooms', bodyparser.json(), (req, res) => {

let rooms;

try {
    rooms = {
        id:req.body.id,
        name: req.body.name
    };
    createRessource(filename)
    res.status(201).send(rooms);
} catch (error) {
    res.sendStatus(500)
}
refresh();
```

});

I tested with intellij editor this way:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/rooms
Content-Type: application/json 
{ "name": "Peter", "id": 4}
```

Is http://localhost:3000/rooms not the right endpoint? The get request for this endpoint is o.k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure IntelliJ is not at fault here as I've made many APIs on it (mostly express). If I were you the first thing I would check would be which port is my app listening on.

I assume you are using express (a few reasons such as usage of [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser))

What port did you put in `app.listen(port)`? Maybe you put port 80?

Well considering you are actually receiving a 404 I'll cross that out.

Next thing would be the way you made your app use the router.

Remember, if you did something like

```js
app.use(router, "/api")
```

and in router

```js
router.post("/rooms", function)
```

then your final url to post would be `/api/rooms` and not just `/rooms`. So I suggest what you used on your app. If you don't want to put any preset path then just do

```js
app.use(router)
```

Comment: O.k., I use 
server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port :3000`)
}) and const roomsRoute = require('./Implementierung/Ressourcen/rooms'); + app.use('/rooms', roomsRoute); Anything wrong with it?

Comment: Yeah, from what you have described to me, it seems that you would need to post to /rooms/rooms

Comment: Tried to test POST http://localhost:3000/rooms/rooms, but the result is still 404. Anything else that I can try?

Comment: You could temporarily get rid of the router and put the post directly in same file as app, just for testing

Comment: I tried this in the app.js, still 404. Crazy thing. I tested router.post('/ ', bodyparser.json(), (req, res) with the request POST http://localhost:3000/rooms. This should be right, but it is 404 too.

Comment: well you can try using boduparser.json() seperately, so `app.use(bodyparser.json())` and then `app.post("/rooms", (req, res) => {/*code here*/})`

Comment: Can I separate router.post from router.use(bodyparser.json()) too?

Comment: these are my implemented constants in the file rooms.js const express = require('express');
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const methoden = require('../Methoden/methodenRooms')

router.use(express.json());